# Open databse file using VB input from user

Tags: vb6

Hi Want to open the file as per combobox is selected. 
The below code is not working.

```
Set mydb1 = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase("\\172.22.30.41\Training-Data\Training\Gaus\Vertical Updates & "\" & Combo1.Text & ".mdb")
```

Can anyone point me out what is wrong in the code please?

Comment: It is showing compile error

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your string concatenation where the slash is between `Updates` and `Combo1.Text`. I added the `db` variable for easier readability on this page:

```
Dim db as string
db = "\\172.22.30.41\Training-Data\Training\Gaus\Vertical Updates\" & Combo1.Text & ".mdb"  
Set mydb1 = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(db)
```